# function call inside Angular double curly braces

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

This is my code bit of a heat-map in Kendo UI.

```
<div ng-repeat="h in row.hours" ng-style="h.styleStr" 
    data-value="{{params.compare ? h.percentChange : h.current[unit]}}" 
    data-time="{{$index}}">
        {{params.compare ? h.percentChange : h.current[unit]}}
</div>
```

Its works perfectly fine. what the `h.current[unit]` inside the div, does is, it displays the value (in decimal notation). Like this..[image]
However I need to display the decimal values as integers. Like this...[image]
And I have a `intFormat` function that does just that. For eg:
`intFormat(79.952)` will return `80`. So i'm trying to format the numbers inside the heatmap using the intFormat function. How to achieve this? I don't know if this is legal but I tried `{{params.compare ? h.percentChange : intFormat(h.current[unit])}}`, but its not working. I'm using Angularjs 1X and KendoUI. Can I use function inside the double curly brace?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure you can:

create a function like this

```
$scope.getDisplayValue = function(currentValue)
{
   return intFormat(currentValue);
}
```

And then reference it like this in the html:

```
{{getDisplayValue(h.percentChange)}}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `parseInt(10.5555)`, built in JavaScript convertor in your AngularJS Expression like this: `{{parseInt(10.5555)}}`.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by attaching a filter..like this...
`{{params.compare ? h.percentChange : h.current[unit]|numFmt}}`