# AngularJS format string inside double braces using replace() with regex

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, replace

I am trying to format a MAC address in a table that is populated using AngularJS:

```
<tr ng-repeat="dev in devices">
<td>{{dev.mac.replace(/(.{2})/g,"$1:")}}</td>
</tr>
```

`{{dev.mac}}` works just fine (aside from being unformatted), but when I add the `.replace()` function it breaks. I tried escaping the forward slash based on the error I received, which didn't help. Is `.replace()` not available inside the browser or is there a different syntax for regex inside the double braces or what am I doing wrong?

The goal is to convert AABBCCDDEEFF into AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF as easily as possible within the double braces. As a bonus question, how do I prevent the trailing ':' in the regex (it currently prints AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF:)?

Edit: Adding the error message

> Error: $parse:syntax
>       Syntax Error
>
> Syntax Error: Token '/' not a primary expression at column 20 of the
>   expression [dev.mac.replace(/(.{2})/g,"$&:")] starting at
>   [/(.{2})/g,"$&:"].

That seems to indicate the forward slash is causing the problem, but like I said, escaping it doesn't help.

Comment: Is it due to the limiting quantifier? Try `<td>{{dev.mac.replace(/../g,"$&:")}}</td>`

Comment: I get the same result changing '1' to '&'. I'm updating this post to include the error I get from the browser.

Comment: Use this: dev.mac.replace(new RegExp('(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)'), '$1:$2:$3:$4:$5:$6') inside the curly braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than running your replace inline like that, it'd be better to abstract that out into a function, that should fix any issues you're having with it not getting interpreted correctly. This article shows the right syntax for declaring a function on the scope to call here: [function call inside Angular double curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038244/function-call-inside-angular-double-curly-braces), it should be something like this

```
$scope.fixMacAddress = function(addr)
{
   return addr.replace(/(.{2})/g,"$1:")
}
```

and

```
{{ fixMacAddress(dev.mac) }}
```

Comment: Well that's definitely a solid workaround, hadn't thought going the function route since I was just thinking inline. I'm going to wait before selecting this as the answer in case I do get an inline solution, but if there's a reason inline isn't an option this will be the answer. Also, thanks for not just assuming I already knew how to declare a function inside $scope (I'm well versed, but it's always appreciated to be explicit like that).

Comment: @JWAspin Sounds good, yeah angular's documentation is a bit of a beast so it's always best err on the side of overexplaining when it comes to angular